# Array Data Type insert into MySQL

Tags: mysql

While playing with the[Yelp Dataset](https://www.yelp.com/dataset/documentation/main) using MySql I ran into an interesting issue, evidently i'd like to run some query's, and in the user.json file an "array" of data is described.

How can this "array" be stored in a MySql table?

According to [MySql Reference Documentation for Data Type Storage](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/storage-requirements.html#data-types-storage-reqs-date-time) there doesn't seem to be a data type that will give this result.

> // array of strings, an array of the user's friend as user_ids
>
> "friends":[ "wqoX...", "KUXL...", "6e9r..." ]

So far, i'm doing a simple model to focus on the User table, my creation statement:

```
create table Friends(
friends VARCHAR(255),
primary key (friends));

create table User(
userid VARCHAR(22),
primary key (userid),
friends VARCHAR(22),<--- user-id is 22 so friends-id is 22
foreign key (friends) references UserFriends (friends));
```

Some sample data for fun:

```
insert into User("abcde-ghijk-mnopq-stuv","NONE"); <- person1, no friends
insert into User("abcde-ghijk-mnopq-stuw","abcde-ghijk-mnopq-stuv"); <- person2, person1 friend
```

Perhaps to achieve the results I have to use a database normalization approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Friends` table should contain foreign keys that refer to `Users`:

```
CREATE TABLE Friends (
    user1 VARCHAR(22),
    user2 VARCHAR(22),
    PRIMARY KEY (user1, user2),
    CONSTRAINT user1 REFERENCES User (userid),
    CONSTRAINT user2 REFERENCES User (userid)
);
```

A row in this table indicates that `user1` and `user2` are friends.

In general, you should avoid putting lists into table columns, this is a violation of 2nd Normal Form.

Comment: is there an approach to achieve this using an "n" number of users as friends?

Comment: You can, but it's not a good idea. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad